# Dynamically Fill Jenkins Job Parameter with Github Directory Files

Tags: github, dynamic, jenkins, groovy, parameters

I'm aware of the Dynamic Parameter and Dynamic Extended Choice Parameter plugins. I'm looking for a way to list of text files in a directory in github as drop down list parameter. is there a groovy script or similar that can populate the dropdown with file names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) to fetch a list of files for a given path on a given repo.

So for example, to look inside the `ratpack-groovy/src/main/java/ratpack/groovy` [folder](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/tree/master/ratpack-groovy/src/main/java/ratpack/groovy) of the [ratpack project on github](https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack), you can do:

```
import groovy.json.*

def contents = new JsonSlurper().parse('https://api.github.com/repos/ratpack/ratpack/contents/ratpack-groovy/src/main/java/ratpack/groovy'.toURL())
    .sort { it.type } // Directories first
    .collect { it.name + (it.type == 'dir' ? '/' : '') } // Put a slash on the end of directories

assert contents = ['handling/', 
                   'internal/', 
                   'render/', 
                   'script/', 
                   'server/', 
                   'sql/', 
                   'template/', 
                   'Groovy.java', 
                   'GroovyRatpackMain.java', 
                   'package-info.java']
```

Obviously you can only make [60 requests per hour](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting)

Comment: I tried your script in the extensible choice parameter plugin and the dropdown was empty. I chose the System Groovy Choice Parameter. I also tried the Extended Choice Parameter and Dynamic Choice Parameter and still the dropdowns were empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a solution for git instead of github? I want to do the same thing, but my project is in git and not in github.

Comment: For git, I believe you'd need to clone the repo somewhere :-/

Comment: Is there any way to get param from private repo like this?